# How to show conclusion (i) is proved from the inequality labeled by red rectangle?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Stein174]

The above page is from Stein's Complex Analysis.

How to show conclusion (i) is proved from the inequality labeled by red rectangle?

Comment: It is immediate as the first term is bounded, while the second is asymptotic to $|t|$ at infinity (as $\sigma$ lives in a bounded set and the series is absolutely convergent to a number that depends on $\epsilon$)

Comment: @Conrad Why does $\sigma$ live in a bounded set? The condition is that $\sigma\ge \sigma_0$.

Comment: Because you can always take $\sigma \le 2$ when bounding RZ at infinity in $t$ since obviously RZ is bounded for example by $\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$ when $\sigma \ge 2$. Note that $|t| \ge 1$ means that we have no problems with $\frac{1}{s-1}$ when $\sigma$ near $1$ Inequality (i) above is only of interest for $\sigma \le 1+\epsilon$ as otherwise RZ is bounded